# Angular Test with mockedService doesn't return the mocked Data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Obviously I'm still missing an important thing of understanding on mocking services and I would be very happy for some input.

The code I want to test in my component is:

```
modulesToDisplay: any[] = [];

...

getModules() {
  this.configService.getModulesToDisplay().subscribe(modules => {
    this.modulesToDisplay = modules;
    }
  );
}
```

I would like to test if modulesToDisplay is reassigned when I get something from the Service. So in my Testfile I created a serviceMock which returns an array with two items

```
let configServiceMock: any;

...

beforeEach(async(() => {
  configServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfigService', ['getModulesToDisplay']);
  configServiceMock.getModulesToDisplay.and.returnValue( of(['firstmodule', 'secondmodule']) );

  ...

providers: [
        { ConfigService, useValue: configServiceMock }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

    it('should assign result to modulesToDisplay', () => {
    component.getModules();
    expect(component.modulesToDisplay.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
...
```

I expected this test to pass since I thought calling 'component.getModules();' in my test would use the mocked data. But it doesn't and `modulesToDisplay` remains the empty array which I initialized in my component. So I guess I still didn't understand the correct principle of mocking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `of` should emit your mocked value, I suspect you may still need to execute this in an async context. What happens if you change your spec to:

```
it('should assign result to modulesToDisplay', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.getModules();
  flushMicrotasks();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.modulesToDisplay.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
}));
```

Usually when my mocks appear to not be used, it is related to the mocked object that I provide to the configuration not matching the object provided to the TestBed.configureTestingModule.

There are two ways that I have tried that gets round this.

1.) Instead of building the provider with `useValue`, switch to `useFactory` like so:

```
...
providers: [{ provide: ConfigService, useFactory: () => configServiceMock }]
```

2.) Another approach is to get the service for testing after it has been configured like so:

```
const csMock = jasmine.createSpyObject('ConfigureService', [...]);

TestBed.configureTestingModule(
...
providers: [{ provide: ConfigureService, useValue: csMock }]
);
configServiceMock = TestBed.get(ConfigureService);
```

Comment: No succes :( - modulesToDisplay remains the empty array

Comment: I added a call to detect changes to the spec, though I don't see how it would actually help. Can you confirm that the service is mocked when the `it` is executed? I often check this kind of thing with `console.log`.

Comment: Hm. it seems to be a problem with the mocked service. If I change my specfile to:
...
    }).compileComponents();
configService = TestBed.inject(ConfigService);
configService.getModulesToDisplay = () => of(['test1', 'test2']);
...
it works - but I still don't really get the difference

Comment: If you change that to: spyOn(configService, 'getModulesToDisplay').and.returnValue(of['test1', 'test2']); does it work as expected? My guess is that your mock is not actually getting used. Sometimes I find that changing the provider to use `useFactory: ( )=> configServiceMock helps or fetching the service with configService = TestBed.get(ConfigService) after the you configure the testing module ensures that what you are testing with is the same object that is provided to your class. HTH

Comment: I updated my response to reflect these ideas. It is hard to understand your configuration with what is missing, so I am really just telling you the ways that I fix troublesome specs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think the main error was my incorrect setup of the provider. But I also used your comments to get a better understanding of what happens. So now I'm able to log all the mocked data and the test runs, now. Starting with testing is quite a challenge...

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is very straight forward. Let me help you:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  ...

  providers: [
        { ConfigService, useClass: MockConfigService}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should assign result to modulesToDisplay', () => {
    component.getModules();
    expect(component.modulesToDisplay.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
```

**mock class**

```
export class MockConfigService{
   getModulesToDisplay(){
     return of({
         // whatever module object structure is
     })
   }
}
```

This would work like a charm. I would strongly recommend you to [this article which has a real world example to test a component](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49). For the basics, [this article would be helpful](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7)

Comment: Also on this one: sorry for my delayed answer. It took me some time to try all these different approaches. Your answer works fine! Thanks for that approach

Comment: thanks for your input. On this one I accepted nephiws answer as the correct one since his work solved the problem on my setup